# Where can I find Sitecore 9 demo website?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

I’d like to find easy to setup Sitecore 9 demo website. Imagine this procedure:

- Install Sitecore through Azure marketplace (or jsut have any default Sitecore deployment)
- Install one Sitecore installation package on Content Management instance and publish
- Have a fully functional demo website
- Very similar to http://launchsitecore.net/ but for Sitecore 9+.

I do not want to:

- Setup local development environment
- Install any other tools and software
- Rebuild solution, run gulp etc.

I know about Habitat, but it is not very trivial to setup.

Do you know if such one package install demo website exist?

Answer (score 3):

I realize you mentioned you already know about Habitat, but for others who come looking for an answer to this I'll drop the link to the Habitat Home repositories:

- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Content
- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Commerce

These allow you to tell a full end-to-end Commerce and Content experience with everything ready for you.

### Habitat Home Demo websites

The front-end of the Experience Platform demo can be viewed here: https://experienceplatform.habitathomedemo.com/

The front-end of the Experience Commerce demo can be viewed here:
https://experiencecommerce.habitathomedemo.com/

### App Source

There is also a 'no installation required' demo available from App Source, but this is currently running on version 8.2 (it will be updated to 9.x in the future):

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/web-apps/sitecore.sxp_824?tab=Overview